# Call javascript function in c# actionlink

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html.actionlink

Im trying to re-write this code to c# just for education purpose, i cant get it working tho :( what am i missing?

```
<a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a>
```

This is how far i've gotten:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Log off", "", "", new { onclick = "LogOutLink();" })
```

and the javascript:

```
 <script>
function LogOutLink() {
    document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit();
}
</script>
```

what am i missing? since i dont want the link to call any specific view or controller i have just left them blank as u can see, but it still wants to call for that function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply will need to rewrite it as:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Log off", "", "", new { }, new { onclick = "LogOutLink(); return false;" })
```

If you refer to this [MSDN document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Object,System.Object%29), you will notice that the 4th argument is route values, and the 5th argument is the HTML attributes.

If you have jQuery loaded, you may also use jQuery to do it:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Log off", "", "", new { id = "LogOffId" });
```

In your javascript, add:

```
$(function(){
    $('#LogOffId').on('click', function(){
        $('#logoutForm').submit();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but the link just takes me back to my startpage, might be som fault in the javascript?

Comment: @PerKällström What happens when you add 'return false;' at the end of onclick.  In other words, "LogOutLink(); return false;"

Comment: 10 cookies for you sir, you are my savior of the day!

Comment: @PerKällström Glad I could help sir. I also added the jQuery way to do it for others who may run into the same problem.

Comment: how would i do to add a id to the link? as in add another htmlproperty or whats it called since new { onclick = "LogOutLink(); return false;" } occupy that, can i have 2 properties?

Comment: ok managed to make it on my own, tried to set id after onclick... worked fine if i put it before the onclick =)